# Fusion-IO ioDrives in SQL Server cluster

Tags: sql-server, windows-cluster, tempdb

Has anyone successfully set up a Fusion-io ioDrive (or similar product) in a Windows cluster for SQL Server?  (I would be interested in either Windows Server 2003 or 2008 and SQL Server 2005 or 2008).

We are looking into the possibility of setting up 2 cards on each node in the cluster (RAID 1) to house the TempDB database.

Specifically we are interested in how you would trick windows clustering service to recognize this local "drive" as a cluster resource. (I'm well aware this is unsupported by MS).

Comment: I suspect the reason there's no answers is because it can't be done. My knowledge of clustering isn't very vast, but I can think of a lot of barriers that will stop this from being technically possible.

Comment: You may want to look at a RAMSAN if your IOPS requirements are really this high, and you absolutely must cluster.

Answer (score 2):

tempdb is disposable and rebuilt on restart anyway.

I'd try moving it to the local disks and see what happens. You shouldn't need to add them as a resource. YMMV of course.

User databases + master, msdb, model etc should be on the shared disks

Edit:

- [MS Connect. Not supported apparently](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/532759/support-local-disk-location-for-tempdb-in-failover-cluster-installation)...
- ...[but some guy managed it anyway](http://nyc-dba.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-local-disks-in-cluster.html)

Like I said, YMMV

Comment: That is a most excellent hack, and right up there at the top of the list of things you do only if you know EXACTLY what you're doing and why.

Comment: Thanks for the second link! (I was unfortunately already aware of the first one)

Answer (score 0):

Please find (MVP) Jonathans experience doing this exact same thing with Fusion IO cards.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/0cea0082-24ef-4843-9720-15e3593926ac